# Handling List-types with Esqueleto

Tags: sql, list, haskell, esqueleto

I have data types defined as:

```
data ComitteeView = CommitteeView { committeeId :: CommitteeId
                                  , committeeMembers :: [Person] 
                                  }

data CommitteesView = CommitteesView { committeeView :: [CommitteeView] }
```

Now, as it stands, I have a Persistent model defined as:

```
Person
  name  Text

Committee
  name  Text

CommitteePerson
  personId    PersonId
  committeeId CommitteeId
```

I can pretty easily create a query to populate a CommitteeView, using Esqueleto.  It would go something like this:

```
getCommitteeView cid = 
  CommitteeView <$> runDB $ 
    select $
      from (person `InnerJoin` pxc `InnerJoin` committee) -> do
        on  (committee ^. CommitteeId ==. pxc ^. CommitteePersonCommitteeId)
        on  (person ^. PersonId       ==. pxc ^. CommitteePersonPersonId)
        where_ (committee ^. CommitteePersonCommitteeId ==. val cid)
        return person
```

Now, consider the problem of populating `CommitteesView`.  In principle, we get enough data to populate by running subquery in the above query.  Okay, fair enough. Now how can I use "group by Haskell-list" like `group by` in SQL? How can I fold rows so that I can end up with a list of lists of people?

I get the impression that `esqueleto` can't handle the case as such (i.e., it doesn't have a combinator that would do it).  And my underlying database obviously doesn't support Haskell lists as a column.  But, surely, I can't be the only person to face this issue.  What is an effective strategy?  Folding an n-list of lists into a n-list?  Or running `n+1` queries?  Are there any other options?

Comment: Have you looked at `Data.List.groupBy`?

Comment: @cdk: Yeah, that's what I've been going with.  It gets surprisingly hairy, though.

Answer (score 2):

Esqueleto is **NOT** meant to handle list of sublists (multidimensional list) out of the box yet! `Data.List.groupBy` that 'cdk' advised to you can group only list itself, but not what you was asking for.

For your case I would insistently advise you to use a classic SQL queries. You can run n+1 queries, but do that only if it is rare and not often usable function, that for example prepares cached data (based on your variables names I suppose that it may not be heavy used and it worth a try). For heavy usage you should consider using classic SQL without any doubt.

If you will go to https://github.com/prowdsponsor/esqueleto you will find that:

> Not all SQL features are available, but most of them can be easily
>   added (especially functions).

so you can try to ask for a new feature. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a link to a source on this ?   I'll be happy to award the bounty if someone can verify this is the correct answer or you can provide some kind of documentation.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 If you go on [haskell website](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-1.3.4.2/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html) you will find complete list of examples and use cases and none of them uses multidimensional lists, even "inner join". If you search for a "group by" there, you will find that it can be used for enclosing multiple columns in a tuple or sorting by additional aggregate function. It is also says there that developers try to make Esqueleto as much flexible to support any query, so you can ask for additional extension [here](https://github.com/meteficha/esqueleto).